# How do I create a for loop that tests an input against the key values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a menu from a nested dictionary. I can make it run using individual if statements for a static dictionary however, I would like to be able to append new key/value pairs to the dictionary without writing new if statements for the updated key/value pairs. Here's what I tried:

```
    for entry in dict_key:
        print(entry)
    iquant = input(">")

    for entry in dict_key:
        if iquant == dict_key:
            add = int(input(">"))
            idict[idict_key] += add
```

It runs but passes to the line of code under the second for loop without taking an input.

Comment: Please add all of your code, i.e., what are your `idict`, `dict_key`, etc. I don't quite understand what you would like to achieve, can you clarify your problem more?

Answer (score 0):

if you want add news items in dic

for add new item in dic is

```
dic.update({
    "nameKeyValue": "Value"
})
```

for remove item in dic is

```
dic.pop("nameKeyValue")
```

for edit value item in dic is

```
dic["namekey"] = value;
```

example:

```
dic = {
  "data1","data1",
  "data2","data2"
}

keyname = input("KeyName: ")
value = input("Value: ")
dic.update({
    keyname:value
})#add item
dic.pop(keyname) #delete item
dic[keyname] = value #update data item
```

Comment: I appreciate this rundown of dictionary operations! I figured out what was wrong with the if statement in my second for loop. if iquant == entry: performs as expected